# How to add information to objects that take 2 IDs as parameters without over writing it when info is added again?

Tags: java, loops, object, arraylist

So, ill start with a brief explanation so that my code makes sense. We are reading a file through a scanner and adding every "N" lines to a "Block" that carries those lines (Basically an array list within the object "Block"). 
Every Block is then added randomly to a "DataNode" that has an "int MachineID" and an "int NodeID" (one machines can hold several data nodes and data nodes are just objects that carry an array list of "Blocks").
I have wrote the a method that reads a file after taking its location as parameter and then starts filling up the lines found with lines and then adding the blocks to the nodes. However, I have found that my code creates a new node of determined machine ID and node ID every time a block needs to be added (blocks are added randomly to the machines and nodes) but there is a possibility for one node to hold 2 blocks but what I have written (the code), over writes the previously created node every time i want to add a block to the array list of the node.

Here is my code: (this is a part of a much bigger problem so hope this makes sense)

```
public void createFile(String fileNameOriginal, String fileNameDFS  ) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.fileNameOriginal = fileNameOriginal;
    this.fileNameDFS = fileNameDFS;
    int randomMachine;
    int randomNode;

    File f = new File(fileNameOriginal);
    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(f);

    while(readFile.hasNextLine()){
        //IDs locating the node the block is going to be added to
        randomMachine = (int)(Math.random()*machines);
        randomNode = (int)(Math.random()*nodes);

        Block b = new Block(randomMachine, randomNode);
        // number of lines per block are decided in the class as parameter
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
            b.add(readFile.nextLine());
        }
        // this here is my problem... everything is over written... :'(
        DataNode N = new DataNode(randomMachine, randomNode);
        N.addToNode(b);
    }


}
```

if you have taken the time to read the entire thing I thank you. :)

Comment: The issue is right there under your comment saying there is a problem--You are creating a new data node each time and then adding the block to the new node. If you want to append the block onto an existing node, you are going to need to use the `randomNode` index you created to pull the DataNode from your list of existing nodes

Comment: @ Easton Bornemeier how do u suggest i do that? the number of nodes and number of machines are entered by the user in the Test Class as parameters. i was going to create a forloop that creates all nodes but i then realized the loop over writes everything except the last node... How do u suggest going about the matter (keep in mind i can add any method to any class as neeeded).

Comment: Well your Machine class should have an ArrayList of DataNodes per your description of it, am I correct? I would create all of your Nodes before doing anything with blocks if you are going to randomly assign blocks to machines and nodes. If you are having issues creating and adding to that ArrayList I would post a separate question regarding that issue, this as a whole i pretty broad considering the issue is not with adding blocks to nodes but rather  the setup of your class structure as a whole

Comment: well there is no machine class according to my professor. to be honest i have no idea what to do... i reached a dead end and im following word for word the problem and the design given to us by the Teacher's assistant.
well thanks for trying to help man i really appreciate it.